# I don't understand why one code works and the other doesn't

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I tried plotting some homework and quiz score side by side and I have two sets of code that to me are similar enough but one produces two histograms side by side and the other does not.

I'm running my code in an Anaconda python 3.6 environment on Windows. The following code will set up the problem

```
    data = pd.DataFrame( np.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 100, size = (224,3)))
    data.columns = ['Section', 'hw_score', 'quiz_score']

    data['Section'] = data['Section'].apply(get_section)
    data.head(10)


    data['hw_score'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
    data['quiz_score'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
    data.isnull().sum()

    data.hw_score[ data.hw_score > 0 ].hist( bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] )

    data.quiz_score[data.quiz_score > 0].hist( bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] )
```

I'm not sure why the following code does not produce histograms that are side by side:

```
plt.figure( figsize = (15,6) )
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
fig = data.hist(column='hw_score')
fig.set_title('Homework Score')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
fig = data.hist(column='quiz_score')
fig.set_title('Quiz Score')
```

and the following does:

```
plt.figure( figsize = (15,6) )
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
fig = data.hw_score[ data.hw_score > 0 ].hist( bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] )
fig.set_title('Homework Score')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
fig = data.quiz_score[data.quiz_score > 0].hist( bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] )
fig.set_title('Quiz Score')
```

Comment: how is this function 'get_section' defined?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ it doesn't matter just delete that line, he doesn't use it in the problematic section of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your misfiring code `fig` is a numpy array where the zeroth element is a `AxesSubplot` object. The `pandas` docs [warn](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist) about that.

It also tells you that you can pass an `ax` directly to `pandas.DataFrame.hist` which we can edit your misfiring code to do like so:

```
fig = plt.figure( figsize = (15,6) )
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
data.hist(column='hw_score', ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Homework Score')

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
data.hist(column='quiz_score', ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Quiz Score')

plt.show()
```

Note the changes: `fig` is now the actual figure,  `ax` the axes. The return type of `data.hist` is a numpy array of axes, but we don't need that and can decide not to store it anywhere.

**EDIT:** So you followed up to ask why the other code block DID work. In short, it's because the `pandas` devs like to implement methods for both `pandas.DataFrame` and `pandas.Series`. So, when you call:

```
fig = data.hw_score[ data.hw_score > 0 ].hist( bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] )
```

`data.hw_score[ data.hw_score > 0 ]` is a `pandas.Series`. Having a look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.hist.html) for `pandas.Series.hist`, there's no warning about sometimes returning a `numpy` array as with `pandas.DataFrame.hist`.

Since it doesn't return an object wrapped in an array we don't need to take any special measures to access the `AxesSubplot` object.

Comment: Thank you! Why doesn't the same error appear when I use the last set of code instead?

Comment: That's a little complicated to answer in a comment so I edited my answer @Skylar.Trigueiro